# GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier return null

Tags: kotlin, token, ktor

I use...

```
try {
        val verifier = GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(NetHttpTransport(), GsonFactory())
            .setAudience(listOf(AUDIENCE))
            .setIssuer(ISSUER)
            .build()
        verifier.verify(tokenId)
    }catch (e : Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        null
    }
```

to verify google token id..
but verify function return nothing and catch block runs..

And this message is displayed...

[click to see error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8qVD.png)

The token is valid and also I used VPN but the result was still the same And also I use localhost

The solutions I saw and used

1. Using VPN and DNS
2. use accounts.google.com Instead https://accounts.google.com

Thank you if you have a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved...

**Solution:** Use another VPN and the problem is solved